# ChromeDriver - Network Performance Logging: Understanding timing section of Network.responseReceived

Tags: performance, logging, selenium-chromedriver, timing

I am trying to understand the relationship between the attributes in the timing section of network performance log message.

Setup: I am running ChromeDriver with Network Performance Logging. I am pulling out the log messages (Selenium - Java).
Below is sample log message and my understanding so far.

```
message => params => response => timing
{
    "requestTime": 126550.470936,          : Time in sec when the browser knows the call has to be issued?
    "proxyStart": 1.77299999631941,        : Is this a relative time in ms from requestTime? What this latency accounts for?
    "proxyEnd": 3.25700000394136,          : Time taken to resolve the proxy in ms?
    "dnsStart": -1,                        :  
    "dnsEnd": -1,                          : Time taken to resolve the dns?
    "connectStart": -1,                    :
    "connectEnd": -1,                      : Time taken to establish the connection with remote server? 
    "sslStart": -1,                        :
    "sslEnd": -1,                            : Is this part of "connect" section? (time taken to negotiate SSL handshake?)
    "workerStart": -1                      :
    "workerReady": -1,                     : 
    "sendStart": 582.229000006919,         : 
    "sendEnd": 582.65900000697,            : Time taken to send the request to server?
  "pushEnd": 0,                          :
    "pushStart": 0,                        : Unclear as what this accounts for.
    "receiveHeadersEnd": 1218.61900000658  : Time taken to completely receive the header?
}
```

I am trying to understand the following parts from the above timing split.

- Time taken by browser to issue the request (typical Queuing delay
  visible in network tab).
- Time taken by the browser to establish the connection and send the request
- Time taken by the server to process the request
- Time taken to receive the response.

Any pointers on this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answers from another group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/FCCV2J7BaIY

Comment: Based on above, the response timing object is defined at  [ResourceTiming](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-ResourceTiming) on Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer page.

Answer (score 1):

These are my understanding

*Latency* is **receiveHeadersEnd**.

*Proxy time* is **proxyEnd - proxyStart**.

*Send time* is **sendEnd - sendStart**.

*Waiting time* is **receiveHeadersEnd - sendEnd**.

**Plese Refer:**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/cuIpVMC1C4U

Comment: Thanks for the help and reference. I need to measure the following aspects for performance reasons. Queuing : time difference between when the browser knows that it has to issue the request till it actually issues the request,  Blocking : time taken to establish the connection (proxy, connect, ssl), Sending, TTFB, Downloading (for measuring performance aspects). In above, receiveHeadersEnd is measured from response.timing.requestTime? Also does "Waiting time" indicate the TTFB? Thanks again.